# C# runtime compilation complains The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, compilation, roslyn, runtime-compilation

I am trying to use Roslyn to compile C# code at runtime. My compilation function is as follows:

```cs
using System.Collections.Immutable;
using Basic.Reference.Assemblies;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Emit;

namespace RuntimeCompiler;

public static class RuntimeCompiler
{
    public static void Compile(string sourceCode, string outputPath, string assemblyName="MyAssembly")
    {
        var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(sourceCode);
        var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(assemblyName)
            .WithOptions(new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary))
            .AddReferences(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location))
            .AddSyntaxTrees(syntaxTree);
    
        using var stream = new FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.Create);
        var result = compilation.Emit(stream);

        if (result.Success) return;
        throw new Exception($"Compilation failed");
    }
}
```

and my driver function is below:

```cs
namespace RuntimeCompiler;

public class main
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        const string sourceCode = @"
            namespace UtilityLibraries;

            public static class StringLibrary
            {
                public static bool StartsWithUpper(this string? str)
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
                        return false;

                    char ch = str[0];
                    return char.IsUpper(ch);
                }
            }";
        const string outputPath = @"/tmp/mylib3.dll";
        RuntimeCompiler.Compile(sourceCode, outputPath, "ass3");
    }
}
```

The code works, and I can see my dll being generated. The problem is, when I try to use the dll in a separate ConsoleApp like below:

```cs
using UtilityLibraries;

StringLibrary.StartsWithUpper("asdasd");
```

Compiler complains:

> The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'.

I also examined the value of `typeof(object).Assembly.Location`, it is `/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.25/System.Private.CoreLib.dll` so it appears to me that the requested assembly is already added.

Any thoughts?

(In case anyone is interested in taking a closer look, I uploaded a minimally reproducible example [here](https://github.com/alex-lt-kong/the-nitty-gritty/tree/main/csharp/compilation-on-the-fly))

Comment: Try adding the requested Dll, it should be in the same directory `typeof(object).Assembly.Location`. Also maybe `mscorlib.dll` is also required.

Comment: @CSharpie tried adding `mscrolib.dll` and multiple combinations of different `dll`s. The error is still the same...

Comment: Hmm thats what we do and it works. Is it maybe Framework Version related problem?
Are you compiling both against .net 6?

Comment: Did you compile and use the dll on different platforms?

Comment: @shingo no, same platform.

Comment: @CSharpie yes, both the RuntimeCompiler class and the Test class targets dotNet 6. Perhaps let me share a repo link, see if you can reproduce my error.

Comment: @CSharpie here you go: https://github.com/alex-lt-kong/the-nitty-gritty/tree/main/csharp/compilation-on-the-fly

Comment: Try adding _all_ of the following:`netstandard.dll Microsoft.CSharp.dll mscorlib.dll System.Private.CoreLib.dll`

I can not test it, but this is essentially what we do.

Comment: @CSharpie problem is not with dynamic compilation but with addition of the dll to the project. Invoking the method dynamically when loading with `Assembly.Load` works

Comment: @D.J.Elkind why exactly do you want to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you have is related to what assemblies you are adding. Start from [this comment @github](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/16211#issuecomment-270462911):

> This behavior is "By Design". On .NET Core all of the core types are actually located in a private DLL (believe the name is `System.Private.Corlib`). The mscorlib library, at runtime, is largely a collection of type forwarders. The C# compiler is unable to resolve these type forwarders and hence issues an error because it can't locate `System.Object`.
>
> This is a bit of a known issue when working on .NET Core. There is a stricter separation of runtime and compile time assemblies. Attempting to use runtime assemblies as compile references is not supported and frequently breaks do to the structure of the runtime assemblies.

And then check the [Runtime-code-generation-using-Roslyn-compilations-in-.NET-Core-App.md](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/wiki/Runtime-code-generation-using-Roslyn-compilations-in-.NET-Core-App.md) doc. What you are actually doing is compiling against runtime (implementation) assemblies which breaks adding compiled dll as reference to the project. You want to compile against reference ones to do that:

> ##### [Compile against reference (contract) assemblies](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/wiki/Runtime-code-generation-using-Roslyn-compilations-in-.NET-Core-App.md#compile-against-reference-contract-assemblies)
>
> This is what the compiler does when invoked from msbuild. You need to decide what reference assemblies to use (e.g. `netstandard1.5`). Once you decide, you need to get them from nuget packages and distribute them with your application, e.g. in a form of embedded resources. Then in your application extract the binaries from resources and create MetadataReferences for them.
> To find out what reference assemblies you need and where to get them you can create an empty .NET Core library, set the target framework to the one you need to target, build using `msbuild /v:detailed` and look for `csc.exe` invocation in msbuild output. The command line will list all references the C# compiler uses to build the library (look for `/reference` command line arguments).

I have changed 2 things to make the code to work:

1. Use reference assembly (path may differ on you machine depending on the actual SDK installed and OS, maybe there is a better approach instead of hardcoding)

   ```cs
   var assemblyPath = "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\packs\\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\\6.0.25\\ref\\net6.0";
   var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(sourceCode);
   var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(assemblyName)
       .WithOptions(new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary))
       .AddReferences(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "System.Runtime.dll")))
       .AddSyntaxTrees(syntaxTree);
   ```
2. Consolidated the assembly name and file name:

   ```
    <ItemGroup>
      <Reference Include="ass3">
        <HintPath>ass3.dll</HintPath>
      </Reference>
    </ItemGroup>
   ```

   and

   ```cs
   const string outputPath = @"/tmp/ass3.dll";
   ```

###### Notes

- I would argue that this is a bit unconventional approach to the problem. If you want "dynamic"/build-time code generation - consider using [source generators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview)
- If source generator is not an option - consider generating a project and compiling a whole project
- If you still want to utilize your way you can try something like the following (see [this comment @github](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/2082#issuecomment-442713181)):

  Add to the generator .csproj:

  ```
  <PropertyGroup>
      <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
  </PropertyGroup>
  ```

  Add `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel` nuget and use it to get the references:

  ```
  MetadataReference[] refs = DependencyContext.Default.CompileLibraries // filter out some libs?
      .SelectMany(cl => cl.ResolveReferencePaths())
      .Select(asm => MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(asm))
      .ToArray();
  ```

  Also you can try compiling against .NET Standard references.
- Your current approach allows to load assembly dynamically and call methods with reflection. For example:

  ```
  var assembly = Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(outputPath));
  var type = assembly.GetType("UtilityLibraries.StringLibrary");
  var methodInfo = type.GetMethod("StartsWithUpper", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
  var result = methodInfo.Invoke(null, new Object[] { null });
  ```

Comment: Just tested, your code works. But now the problem is, how can I get `var assemblyPath = "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\packs\\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\\6.0.25\\ref\\net6.0";` programmatically?

Comment: @D.J.Elkind see the updated notes.

Comment: The revised post works like a charm. I believe I understand most points you mentioned, but I am not quite sure about the source generator approach. What are the difference between your "source generator" approach and my approach? My end goal is this: we want to have a dll as a plugin to our program. The function defined in this dll is on the critical path and will be called millions (if not billions) of time. But the function is not 100% known at compiled time. So we want to compile the dll based on some runtime info and load it to the main program as a "plugin".

Comment: so that we can avoid runtime cost by not using techniques such as reflection. The dll plugin, as I envisage, should run exactly as fast as as if it is build beforehand at compile time.

Comment: @D.J.Elkind was glad to help. If answer works for you - feel free to upvote and mark it as accepted one (checkmark to the left). The [mre] you have provided is compile time generation. Exactly what source generators a for.